# Use of Objective C block from Swift

Tags: objective-c, closures, block, compatibility

I have a library written in Obj C and I want to use it in my Swift project, so I added the headers to the bridging-header and xcode recognizes the classes from Obj C files...

The problem is that I want to use this block from swift

```
typedef void (^ASDataGridRowCellHandler) (ASDataGridRowCell * cell, id cellValue, ASDataGridColumnDefinition *columnDefinition, int rowNumber, NSArray *rowData, BOOL rowIsSelected);
```

Is there any way to auto-generate the closure in Swift using Xcode?
I dont want to migrate the code in Swift, only use it from my project

I have tried the following

```
varWhichNeedsToBeABlock = {(vars...) -> Void in <Statements...>}
```

but I does not work, I think It would be easier if Xcode generates the code automatically...

Thanks in advance